# Select statement with variable not working

Tags: bash, variables, select, syntax, jq

I am trying to do a select statement and I am having issues passing in a variable. My code pattern is shown below :

```
sD=$(hostname)
echo $sD #prints TEST

select (.name=="$sD") # this line isnt working. When i do

select (.name=="TEST") # it works properly
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: See: `help select` or https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+select+example

Comment: Was this intended as a `jq` question or something?

Comment: Yes A field unique to my system in a variable then comparing it to jq results

Comment: any help? I am still struggling